# How to improve this rendering so it looks more like the target image? (Disaster)

Tags: rendering, materials, texturing, shaders

I'm trying to replicate the following image using Blender:

[the image http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03k.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03k.png)

For this, I've used MakeHuman to generate a similar-looking human, an ortographic camera and a Lattice to deform the mesh (to give that specific distorted projection). I've set the render size to 64x64 (the original image is 32x32) and used FreeStyle for outlines. I'm also using a Sun Lamp and I've deactivated anti-aliasing. This is what I got:

[blender http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03o.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03o.png)

But rendering results are terrible:

[results http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03l.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03l.png)

I have that feeling that I've done everything I could to get close to it but somehow it still fails miserably. The color is pale, the image is blurry, the outline is wrong in hands and face. I don't know what else to do.

[Link to the .blend](http://www.filedropper.com/disasterguloid)

[Original 32x32 target image](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/03m.png)

Comment: This question is impossible to understand without the links. Now that the links are dead the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at his ankles in the target image, they do not seem to be proportioned like normal human ankles -- they look MUCH too thick. I suspect the creators of that figure ran into the same problems you did with trying to generate a realistic looking figure on such a small scale and compensated by not using anatomically accurate proportions.

So, if you want to try to use Blender's environment to make your figure, I would recommend finding proportions that might not look correct in the 3D Viewport or in MakeHuman, but that do look correct when rendered at 32x32.

It is also possible that the original creators did not use a 3D model rendered at 32x32, but rather just painted the image by hand, pixel by pixel, or perhaps used some process other than rendering from a 3D environment.

Another possibility is to render your figure at a much higher resolution so you get all the details you want, and then shrink it down & selectively edit it in Photoshop.

Comment: Hello, thanks. The original image is hand drawn, our team is trying to replicate it using models to generate a huge amount of combinatoric sprites (unfeasible to touch manually). I'll be trying to deform the mesh to look better after rendering, but I'm mainly worried with the colors and lack of details in the image. I've improved to [this](http://o7.no/1hZr9bu), but it still looks really blurry and pale.

Comment: I suggest heavily evagerating the colors, and also exagerating the sharpness and size of the features. In fact, you might even consider making your own human figure out of cubes -- each cube to represent one pixel in your final render. That might help you get MUCH clearer, sharper features and also help you see much more clearly which faces, edges and vertices need to be edited in order to get the desired result.